# `while y < x` loop never ends

Tags: python

I'm trying out Python, and, in my very tired state, can't seem to find the problem with the code below:

```
import sys

def printNum(x):
    y = 0
    while y < x:
        print "Number: ", y
        y = y + 1

printNum(sys.argv[1])
```

So, I'm trying to get it to print out `y` `x` times. `x` is passed as a parameter. The loop never ends and I don't know why!

Comment: Try casting x to int - `while y < int(x):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this code will paste a `str` into `printNum`, but `printNum` treats the input (`x`) like an `int`. To fix this, convert the input to an `int`:

```
printNum(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: Totally forgot about the parameters being strings. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Ouch!

Your problem is that `sys.argv[1]` gives you a `str`, and a `str` is always greater than an `int`.

For example:

```
>>> '2' < 1
False
>>> '1' < 2
False
```

So what you'll need to do is change your last line to

```
printNum(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `x` value that you get as a command line parameter is passed in as a string, not as an integer. All integers are treated as being less than all strings:

```
>>> 1 < "2"
True
>>> 3 < "2"
True
>>> 1000000 < "2"
True
```

...so your loop will never end.

try:

```
 printNum(int(sys.argv[1]))
```